# How to install Electrum wallet in an offline Linux computer?

Tags: electrum, linux, ubuntu, python, coldstorage

So I want to play with the Electrum wallet, but as Cold Storage.

Then what I plan to do is to install a raw Ubuntu 16.04 LTS into a computer "A" which I will never plug to the internet.

So, with computer "B" that has internet connection, I first download all dependencies of electrum from `apt` guided by [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685200/544947):

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris --yes -d --reinstall install python-qt4 python-pip $(sudo apt-cache depends yourpackage | grep "  Depends:" |  sed 's/  Depends://' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g') | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 >downloads.list
wget --input-file downloads.list
```

Now I download Electrum's tar.gz file. The last version when writing this is:

```
wget https://download.electrum.org/2.7.12/Electrum-2.7.12.tar.gz
```

Then I download its `pip` dependencies:

```
pip download Electrum-2.7.12.tar.gz
```

Now I copy all the files to a USB disk and then from this disk, to computer A.

And I run:

```
sudo dpkg --install *.deb
sudo pip install Electrum-2.7.12.tar.gz
```

However, the second command fails. It seems that even if I downloaded its `pip` dependencies, it doesn't pick them up and still tries to connect to the internet.

How to go on here then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed a special command to use local storage, which at last worked:

```
sudo pip install Electrum-2.7.12.tar.gz --no-index --find-links `pwd`
```

**UPDATE**: Whenever I've had to do this for the second time, even the first instructions (posted in my question), to get the apt-get dependencies recursively, didn't work. So finally I decided to create a script that does everything for you: https://github.com/knocte/offlineElectrum/blob/master/downloadElectrumAndDeps.fsx